# Check me out - What am I?

Tags: riddle, homonym

Check me out,

Bark silently,

Stamp quietly,

I tire of giving clues,

Should we start a band?

How do I add bullet points?

Something's coming! Duck!

**What am I?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're

> rubber

Check me out,

> Rubber checks

Bark silently,

> Rubber comes from trees which have bark

Stamp quietly,

> Many stamps are made of rubber

I tire of giving clues,

> Tires are made of rubber

Should we start a band?

> Rubber bands

How do I add bullet points?

> Rubber bullets

Something's coming! Duck!

> Rubber ducks

Comment: Speedy.  Well done.  +1